# Update/Edit multiple records selected in Listbox with value from textbox

Tags: ms-access, vba

I got a pretty tricky problem which I cannot solve.

I have an access database of tools stored in a warehouse that are borrowed from it to the production site. I have a table storing data of dates of borrowing and returning items to the warehouse (ofc with other data such as workers ID etc). While item is outside the warehouse,  the returning_date field in the table is empty.

So I created a query that shows only record with returning_date field empty and made a form with a (multi-select) listbox that shows data from query and a textbox that is date formatted. Now what I want to achieve is to be able to select multiple records in the listbox and update selected ones returning date field with a date from the textbox. The problem I have is that I don't know how to recall the certain field in selected records to insert the data there. Is this possible the way I came with? If not, how can I solve this problem?

Edit: for the iteration process I tried to use two types of iteration:

```
For Each varItm In Me.Listbox.ItemsSelected
'update statement should go here
Next varItm
```

and the second one:

```
For i = 0 to Listbox.ItemsSelected.Count - 1
'update statement
Next i
```

I had some problems with variables and missing objects (run time error 424) but the main problem is that I don't know how to insert the data to certain fields of selected rows.

Comment: Use VBA. Iterate through the selected item (ItemsSelected) and run an update statement for each selected item. Refer in the statement to the form field representing the return data. Put the return data textbox in the header of your form. Give it a go yourself first.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know I have to iterate for every selected item, but what update statement should I use? Thought about using recordset, but still, I don't know how to refer to the selected items

Comment: Do you have the iteration code? Edit your question to show it.

Answer (score 2):

Your Listbox should have at least two columns providing data from the source query.  The first should be the ToolID and the second the ToolName (or whatever your field is called that contains the name of the tool).  A nearby button can run the routine you have above, to make sure not to run until all the items are correctly selected.  Then, identify the columns property to get the ID number to run the query against.  Keep in mind though that in Access the first column is 0, just like the first record is 0 in a list box (thus why you have a -1 at the end of the list count).

Here is one method, if you want to call the update routine for each ID individually:

```
Dim ToolID as Long
Dim strSQL as String
For i = 0 To Me.lsbTools.ListCount - 1
    If Me.lsbTools.Selected(i) Then
        ToolID = Me.lsbTools.Column(0, i)
        strSQL = "UPDATE tblTool SET ReturnDate=#" & me.txbDateReturned & "# WHERE ToolID=" & ToolID
        DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL
    End If
Next
```

However, you can also construct the SQL to run one time and update all those included, like this:

```
Dim ToolID as Long
Dim strSQL as String
'The hashtags around the dates ONLY work in MS ACCESS and will not work in T-SQL.  you will have to edit the syntax to use this on a SQL-server linked table
strSQL = "UPDATE tblTool SET ReturnDate=#" & me.txbDateReturned & "# WHERE ToolID IS IN("

For i = 0 To Me.lsbTools.ListCount - 1
    If Me.lsbTools.Selected(i) Then
        ToolID = Me.lsbTools.Column(0, i)
        strSQL = strSQL & ToolID &", "
    End If
Next
'This checks to make sure the last two characters are a comma and space, and removes them
If Right(strSQL,2) = ", " Then                   
    strSQL = Left$(strSQL, Len(strSQL)-2) & ")"
    DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL                    'This runs the SQL statement
End if
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't understand one thing, I was using the first method and it wouldn't work on one of my computers, but works on the second one. 
The only difference I see is that one version of Access is in Polish language and the second one is in English. I get syntax errors in the Polish version (run-time error 3075, syntax error in query expression '#31.12.2017'. - the date after the hashtag is the date I've typed into the date textbox). Do you have any idea what causes this problem?

Comment: Okay, got it, I had to change date settings in Windows to show short date with dashes, not dots. The first method works like a charm, thank you!
Anyway, in the second method, what sould be after 'IS IN' expression in:
strSQL = "UPDATE tblTool SET ReturnDate=#" & me.txbDateReturned & "# WHERE ToolID IS IN("   ? I had some syntax errors in this method too