# Modify multiple records via listbox based on combobox in Access

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access, combobox, listbox

I have a form that has a multi-selection listbox based on a query of items that have a specific field that is blank (UserID).   I would like to select a UserID from a combobox and click a button to have all selected records modified to have that UserID. (I would also like to update the DateAssigned field to whatever the current date is). CaseID is the unique value in the table.

[Sample Form Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdul3.png)

(The combo box has two columns, the second one has the actual ID I'd want to use).

I've looked at multiple different posts on here like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48027291/update-edit-multiple-records-selected-in-listbox-with-value-from-textbox) but I haven't been able to get it to work. Here's an example of a code I found and tried, altered slightly.

```
    Private Sub AssignButton_Click()


Dim lCnt As Long
Dim lID As Long
Dim sSQL_Update As String

Dim sText_1 As String


Dim bSuccess As Boolean

sText_1 = Me.ComboBox


With Me.ToAssignList
    For lCnt = 1 To .ListCount
        If .Selected(lCnt) Then
            lID = .Column(4, lCnt - 1)
            'Example update for 1 column
            sSQL_Update = "UPDATE MainData SET UserID = '" & sText_1 & "' WHERE CaseID = " & lID & ";"
            bSuccess = Update_Statement(sSQL_Update)
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub

Public Function Update_Statement(sUpdate_Stmt) As Boolean

Dim db                          As Database

Set db = CurrentDb
db.Execute (sUpdate_Stmt)
End Function
```

When I try running this nothing happens.

Thank you!

Comment: "haven't been able to get it to work" means what - error message, wrong results, nothing happens? What exactly have you tried? Edit question to provide your code.

Comment: I've tried multiple different types of code listed but I don't know which accomplishes what I'm looking for.    I'll edit and provide one of the codes I found on here adjusted slightly.

Comment: Again, what happens when you run code - error message, wrong result, nothing?

Comment: I stated below the code that nothing happens.

Comment: Oh, okay. Is UserID a number or text field? If number, don't use apostrophe delimiters. Have you step debugged? Set a breakpoint and follow code as it executes one line at a time. Are variables getting correct value?

Comment: Make sure your unshown table structure includes a many to many relationship between users and cases.  For instance: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ms_access/ms_access_many_to_many_relationships.htm  When that is done select each of the tables involved in the many to many relationship in turn and create a form using the ribbon.  Play around with the resulting forms and the tables.  Also replace any textboxes bound to userID with comboboxes bound to userid but with showing users. see here: https://www.techonthenet.com/access/tutorials/combobasics2010/basics08.php

Answer (score 0):

Hy, Some remarks and tweaks to your code :

First enable the direct screen :

[image]

This will enable you to use the debug function.

Is the field : UserID in the table Maindata a text field ? If so, fine, otherwise you should alter the string to :

```
"UPDATE MainData SET UserID = " & Cint(sText_1) & " WHERE CaseID = " & lID & ";"
```

Then it would be better to create different functions in a module for what you are trying to do. But ok, this is not your main concern right now...
Try :

```
Private Sub AssignButton_Click()

Dim lCnt As Long
Dim lID As Long
Dim sSQL_Update As String
Dim sText_1 As String
Dim bSuccess As Boolean

sText_1 = Me.ComboBox

With Me.ToAssignList
    For lCnt = 1 To .ListCount
        If .Selected(lCnt) Then
            lID = .Column(4, lCnt - 1)
            
            'Example update for 1 column
            sSQL_Update = "UPDATE MainData SET UserID = '" & sText_1 & "' WHERE CaseID = " & lID & ";"
            '
            'Check your sql statement and add it to stack overflow if it still is not working
            '
            Debug.Print sSQL_Update
            '
            bSuccess = Update_Statement(sSQL_Update)
                        
        End If
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

There is should be a logical check in the code bellow to see if the update is done, anyhow, the code bellow should work and return a true value if the update doesn't produce an error... it's not good code but ok.

```
 Public Function Update_Statement(sUpdate_Stmt) As Boolean
    
        Dim Currentdb As Database
        Set Currentdb = Currentdb
        
        Call Currentdb.Execute(sUpdate_Stmt, dbSeeChanges)

    Update_Statement = True

End Function
```

Good luck !